# rename the 10 most-recently modified files on AIX

Tags: files, rename, aix

I have some .xls files in a defined directory (say in /A/B). I want to rename top 10 latest files and append "-bkp" in their names.

I tried, not working

```
ls -lt *.xls | head -1 | awk '{print "mv " $9 " "$9-bkp}' | sh
```

I tried find and -exec but how do we get top l0 latest modified files

Answer (score 2):

You should use `-10` and not `-1` as argument to `head`, and you also need quotes around `-bkp`, so

```
 ls -lt *.xls | head -10 | awk '{print "mv " $9 " "$9"-bkp"}' | sh
```

should work. And you would probably have realised if you had tried removing `| sh`, so the command just ends with awk printing the commands.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to make any assumption on what character filenames may contain, you could do:

```
ls -dt ./*.xls | awk -v q="'" -v n=10 '
  function process() {
    if (NR > 1) {
      gsub(q, q "\\" q q, file)
      print "mv " q file q, q file "-bkp" q
      if (!--n) exit
    }
  }
  /\// {
    process()
    file = $0
    next
  }
  {file = file "\n" $0}
  END  {process()}' | sh -x
```

Or if you have `zsh`:

```
for f (*.xls(om[1,10])) cp -- $f $f-bkp
```

Or

```
autoload zmv
zmv -C '*.xls(#qom[1,10])' '$f-bkp'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have ksh93 (for the arrays) and perl (for the timestamp/stat), then this will work:

```
files=(*.xls)
# exit early if there are no matching files
[ "$files" = "*.xls" ] && exit 0

for index in ${!files[@]}
do
  t[$index]=$(perl -e '$x=(stat(shift))[9]; print "$x"' "${files[index]}")
done

for i in ${!t[@]}
do
  printf "%d %d\n" ${t[i]} $i
done | sort -rn  | head -10 | while read t i
do
  mv "${files[i]}" "${files[i]}-bkp"
done
```

It works by gathering the list of *.xls files, then loops over those files, calling the `perl` one-liner to print the last-modified timestamp of each file, saving the result into a parallel array `t`.

It then loops over t, printing the timestamp and the array index, pipes that to `sort` to get the most-recently modified files to the beginning, pipes that to `head` to get the top 10, then loops back over that output to call the `mv` command on the corresponding files.

Answer (score -2):

ls has a "sort"-parameter that can take a value of "time".

```
#!/bin/bash
IFS=$'\n'
for file in $(ls *.xls --sort=time|head -n 10);
do
    mv $file $file-bkp
done
unset IFS
```

The IFS-shenanigans are because the for-loop becomes ill-mannered if you have spaces in your filenames. I believe there are more orthodox solutions to that issue, but my solution works. You can remove the lines containing IFS if you know for a fact that your filenames contain no spaces.

Comment: That `ls` command doesn't work on AIX.  It's just 'ls -t` to sort by time (last modified).

Comment: And `-t` also works on Linux.